# Handling alert appears in a popup window using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, webdriver

The scenario is as follow:

open a page --> this page create another window 
new window --> show alert

now I have two window handles and the second window frozen with the alert msg.

I used the code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                       'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                       'confirmation popup to appear.')
```

My question is to catch up the alert do driver need to be switched to the new window that showed the alert?
Or alert can be caught using `driver.switch_to.alert` regardless of current window handler.

the test page is here: http://alertonpopwindow.bitballoon.com/

thanks,
Mhd.

Comment: You should switch to window in which `alert()` function was called

Comment: what if I have several windows opened and I don't know which one called alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know which window called `alert()`, you can try

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

for window in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(window)
    try:
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
        break
    except NoAlertPresentException:
        pass
```

Comment: The code works after I remove the function brackets from driver.switch_to.alert. But still, I can't accept or dismiss the alert!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh... yep, it's not callable:) Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it helped to solve your problem

Comment: Dismissing or accepting the alert? driver.accept ()?

Comment: `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()` to close alert. `dismiss()` used for `confirm()` pop-ups- kind of pop-up where you can choose, for example, `Ok` (`accept()`) or `Cancel` (`dismiss()`) buttons

Comment: driver.switch_to.alert.accept() is not working. and driver.switch_to.alert.text is none!

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple windows opened,  one alert pop-up and with my code you don't get any exceptions, but alert is still opened?

Comment: Yes, it works with a single window has an alert can catch it and can do accept, text or dismiss.
But when have two I only can sense the alert but can't do anything accept or getting the text.

Comment: It seem that `webdriver` cannot switch to window with already opened alert... Can you tell me how those new windows and popup appears? Do you open new window by clicking on some link or it appears automatically?

Comment: Page 1 :
have javascript function onload event :
window.open ("msg.html","mywindow");

msg.html page
again javascript onload event: alert('something')

Comment: Hi I just upload the html code on free hosting site,
http://alertonpopwindow.bitballoon.com/

Comment: Page is not accessible

Comment: if you load it using this browser, the popup window is automatically disabled, but selenium runs it perfectly.

Comment: Finally !!! This works  Alert(driver).accept()
Thank you for your help.